# why battery don't charge?

Tags: laptop, battery, power

my battery is only 21% charged and don't charge more than this
and if i disconnected the ac the laptop will shut down even though it has 21% charged

some people tell me maybe it's the ac that can't charge the battery anymore 
and i can't find an ac with the same Ampere to test if the battery will charge again

that's my battery [status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZmAT.jpg)

so should i change the battery or what ?

Comment: Take it to a repair shop to get a proper diagnosis (broken battery or broken charging circuitry).

Comment: all the repair shops near me couldn't help + the battery is build in and if i had to buy new one or even ac i will ship it aboard

Comment: As I understand your laptop works normally with your current power supply. This means it is safe. If your laptop shuts down without power supply when battery charge is over the level set to shutdown, the reason can be in the battery or the battery checking scheme is broken. In the first case your laptop must shutdown sharply, in the second case it must turn off normally (like Start-Shutdown selected).

Comment: the laptop shuts down at the same moment i disconnect the ac 
even it already has 21% and that take us to the second problem which is the laptop cannot charge more than this

Comment: Your battery health is at 69% - this means it is passed its use-by date and should be replaced. I wonder if you have a dead cell causing internal current draw, and as a result the battery is no longer able to output enough power when not plugged in.

Comment: btw, you can (from an electricsl pov) use a charger with the same OR higher current rating, provided the voltage is similar. (this might not work properly on a few computers if the computer is negotiating power draw with the charger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i knew the solution for this guys
the clip that connects the battery to the motherboard wasn't connected well
i don't know how, i didn't move my laptop.